# Time period on a moving wedge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

[image]

This question is based on simple SHM but I am stuck in this question.

My approach: I realised firstly that we cannot assume gravity free space because then the wedge might move in any direction which is contradictory . So I assumed the cylinder to be displaced x along the incline and considered forces acting on it gravity and spring force but there will be a pseudo force too acting but how to calculate that ?

Please help me out.

Comment: I've removed a number of comments that were attempting to answer the question and/or responses to them. Please keep in mind that comments should be used for suggesting improvements and requesting clarification on the question, not for answering.

Comment: But @David Z I didn't understand certain parts of the answer given by Dr_Paradox so I was clarifying my doubts. I dont get what was the need to close the question and delete the answer? It was quite an useful and well explained answer.

Comment: Homework-like questions and check-my-work questions are considered off-topic here, particularly when asking about specific computations instead of underlying physics concepts. Homework questions can be on-topic when they are useful to a broader audience. If you intend to modify your question, please read the links above carefully before editing. **Note that answers with complete solutions may be deleted**

Comment: @Saddy That was different. Dr_Paradox's answer was an answer, not a comment, so that's not what my previous comment was about, but as Aaron said, we don't allow complete answers to homework-like problems (including all sorts of educational exercises) that people are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

In the frame of reference of the wedge, the cylinder will have motion only along the incline (since they are never losing contact) so you can balance forces perpendicular to the incline. I would also recommend trying the same problem for a block first instead of the cylinder as the latter one will get a bit more calculative